# How to prove that the sum of multiplication of diagonal square matrices is the same

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given square matrix $Q$ over $\mathbb{R}$ let us  define a number: $t(Q)=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}$, which equals the sum of diagonal members of $Q$. Prove that $t(AB)=t(BA)$ and that no matrices $A,B$ exist such that $AB-BA=I_n$.

For example, if $Q_2$ is the following matrix: \begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\
4&5\\
\end{bmatrix} then  $t(Q_2 I_2)=1 \cdot 1+5 \cdot 1=6.$

I think $t(AB)=t(BA)$ can be proved if we select a matrix where all members except for the diagonal members are zero (because we're not interested in other members).

For example $A_{n}$:
\begin{bmatrix} a_{1i}&0&0  \\
0&\ddots&0\\
0&0&a_{ni}
\end{bmatrix}

and $B_n$:
\begin{bmatrix} b_{1i}&0&0  \\
0&\ddots&0\\
0&0&b_{ni}
\end{bmatrix}

These matrices are square and diagonal and therefore symmetric.  So essentially $A=A^t$ and $B=B^t$ ($^t$=transposed). So $AB$ and $BA$ are themselves symmetric. Then according to the identity $(AB)^t=B^tA^t \Leftrightarrow AB = BA \Rightarrow t(AB) = t(BA)$ because it's the same matrix.

To prove $AB-BA \neq I_n$ can I say that:

1) in order for $AB-BA = I_n$ then $AB_{ii}-BA_{ii} = 1$ needs to hold.

2) but $t(AB)=t(BA) \Rightarrow AB_{ii}-BA_{ii} = 0$ therefore $AB-BA \neq I_n$
?

Comment: (1) This map is known as the _trace_ of the matrix. (2) One can obtain a direct proof of $t(AB)=t(BA)$ by writing out the matrix elements $(AB)_{ij},(BA)_{ij}$ as sums using the definition of matrix multiplication. (3) In your step 1), you should have $(AB)_{ii}-(BA)_{ii}=1$ to avoid ambiguity. (4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that the trace identity $t(AB)=t(BA)$ holds for **all** matrices,
not just diagonal ones. Let's think about $2$-by-$2$ matrices.
If
$$A=\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}}$$
and
$$B=\pmatrix{b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}}$$
then
$$AB=\pmatrix{a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}&*\\*&a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}}$$
and
$$t(AB)=a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}.$$
So, what is $t(BA)$? What if we take different sizes of matrix?

As for the second part, if you know $t(AB)=t(BA)$, what is $t(AB-BA)$?

Comment: I used diagonal matrices just to isolate the diagonal members because we're not required to prove anything about non-diagonal members. Do you think it's not enough? Also regarding $t(AB-BA)$ it will yield a matrix with all the diagonal members equal to $0$ right?

Comment: @Yos You are asked to prove things about $t(AB)$ and $t(BA)$. Now $t(AB)$ depends only on the diagonal entries of $AB$, but the diagonal elements of $AB$ depend on **all** entries of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yeah but I'm supposing that all non-diagonal members of $A,B$ are zeroes so all non-diagonal members of $AB$ are also zeroes, and zeroes don't influence anything.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2=I_2$ is an illustrative example, since in this case $A=B$ has no diagonal part yet the trace is nonzero. So no, it is _not_ sufficient to consider the diagonal parts of your matrices. @Yos